# WAMP will only load on localhost when sessions are used

Tags: php, wamp

I am using WAMPSERVER 3.1.3 64Bit windows 10, whenever I try to load a page that uses sessions and I am not in localhost, it will not load and give me  ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. Whenever a page without sessions is loaded from an outside source it will work fine and redirect until I log in (at which point it starts using sessions) and then refuse to connect.  Because it will load fine on localhost but not from an outside source I believe it is a problem with WAMP. If anyone could please give feedback on the possible causes for this problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to access a site served by WAMPServer from the internet rather than from the PC running WAMPServer?

Comment: It happens both when I access a site served by WAMPServer from the internet rather than from the PC as well as when I type the url of the site into my browser instead of using localhost.

Comment: Start by checking the access and error log.

Comment: I think the sessions may be locking.

Comment: Do yo uhave a Virtual Host defined for the site you are trying to access

Comment: No I do not, ill look that up , thanks :)

Comment: All files are in my www directory so I do not see the need for a virtualhost , should I still create one?

Answer (score 0):

When I loaded from an outside source , that source was still on the wifi network that was being used to host the site. I realized the error only occurs on devices on the network and was neither a problem with PHP or WAMP.